# Remote json call from dynamically loaded code

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I use

```
 $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl, null, function (responseText) {
            $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
        });
```

to load a page inside a div and from the loaded page I tried to use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "link",
    data: { 'device': device, 'latestDate': latestDate },
    dataType:   "jsonp"
})
```

and

```
$.getJSON equivalent.
```

Sometimes I can observe that the link is requested from $.ajax but I never managed to perform the request from $.getJSON.

Is it a really bad technique to call $.getJSON from code that is loaded dynamically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `$.getJSON` is really just a shorthand for `$.ajax`. Its the same function with some minor syntax candy to make your life easier. If `$.ajax` is working for you but `$.getJSON` is not, then I have to conclude that your `$.getJSON` statement is not really equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery's ajax methods they can seem to fail silently. Try attaching some handlers to the ajax() like detailed here http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

More information can be found here - http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/